# How to specify a state when the system does not change in an ASM chart

Tags: digital-logic, design

This may be simple or obvious but I have not found any definite solution by googling.

I want to include a state in my Algorithmic State Machine chart were nothing changes (no operations on registers) until an input signal changes. One way I have thought of doing this is to include an empty state, where an infinite loop constantly polls until the input changes.
Can state boxes be empty in an ASM chart? In other words, is this allowed?
[image: asm chart]

Comment: An *interrupt* is the usual way out of an infinite loop to go process something. Since it is hardware-related, not often shown in a state chart.

Comment: This is not what I asked, I asked about how to specify a state when the system waits for input without doing any processing (for example changing the state of a register).

Comment: If you aren't using an interrupt to detect the input signal, won't you be continuously polling a value in your "empty" loop?

Comment: Yes, it constantly checks the E signal. What I am asking is if it is allowed to have an empty state box like in the chart above.

Comment: Or, in other words, is this ASM chart valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may come across the same problem, I have found some charts with empty boxes in many credible sources, including

> M. Morris Mano, Michael D. Ciletti (2013) **Digital Design**, Fifth Edition, Pearson Education